# Age validation in momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i must create validation to my users age. I use momentJS library,

I create this but does not work,

```
    if(!moment(inputs.birthDate, "DD/MM/YYYY").fromNow() >= 16){
      return this.res.badRequest("You're too young to create new account in this app.")
    }
```

my user must have at least 16 years old to create new account, have somebody any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
moment().diff(moment(inputs.birthDate), 'years') > 16
```

moment() returns the actual date and then you compare to the birth date in years to know if it's more than 16

Comment: Hi, it not work, i use this ```  if(moment().diff(moment(inputs.birthDate), 'years') > 16){
      return this.res.badRequest("You're too young to create new account in this app.")
    }``` and throw me this error: ``` value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.```

Comment: my inputs.birthDate is ```16/04/2005```

Comment: As the error says, your date is not well formatted. You can use moment to get a date object from it or better, store it as a timestamp, and format it only when displaying

Comment: I let you search "from string date to date with momentjs", since it's actually an other question and there are plenty or responses about it ;)